# ¿Como hago para vaciar la "TextBox" luego de escribir pulsando "Buttom" en C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, formularios, visual, c#-8.0

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En los campos "Nombre", "Apellidos", "Dirección" se debe quedar vacío cuando presione agregar

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes el evento `Click` del boton alli podrias poner la propiedad `Text` en blanco, o sea

```
public button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    textbox1.Text = "";
}
```

de esta forma quitas su contenido

Answer (score 0):

Como dice el comentario de **Leandro Tuttini**, pero personalmente prefiero crear un método para no tener que estar escribiendo siempre lo mismo. Ejemplo:

```
private void Limpiar()
{
   tuTextBox1.Text = "";
   tuTextBox2.Text = "";
}
```

Y ya luego lo aplicas a tu botón:

```
public button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   Limpiar();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

es una pequeña aportación a la solucion que te han dado, pero no varia mucho, el principal motivo es que yo creo que se controla mejor ciertos fallos, como el espacio en blanco.

```
private void Limpiar()
{
   tuTextBox1.Text = string.Empty;
   tuTextBox2.Text = string.Empty;
}

public button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   Limpiar();
}
```

O la otra manera de escribir Limpiar() puede ser la siguiente (mi favorita):

```
private void Limpiar()
{
   tuTextBox1.Clear();
   tuTextBox2.Clear();
}
```